# Android library project inside of a library project

Tags: android

I have noticed that certain applications I have won't build any more since the last ADT update.

Here's the scenario:

1. I have a 'common' library, with some functionalities and wrappers I use around most of my projects
2. I have a project library, containing a 'default' version of the application, containing the 'common' library
3. I have 2 projects, one for free and one for full version of the app. Both have lib 2 included (the project library)

When I build and clean the project (and do all the regular magic) everything is ok. But, when I try to run the application an error is thrown:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

As it turns out, the 'common' library is causing the problem

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/package/common/Class$Sample
```

I think the problem is, that the first (common) lib is included in both the library and the final project.

The thing is, I have only added the common lib to the project lib, and it gets automatically added to the final project (I can see the .jar present under 'Library projects' in Eclipse), but I have found no way to remove it.

I have lost numerous hours on this, so any help is - really - appreciated.

*Hope I have been clear enough, it's a messy situation :)*

Answer (score 1):

Hey they made some serious changes to the way lib projects are handled. [Check out Xaviers post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html) on the android blog about it, it helped me figure mine out.

Comment: Ok, turns out this is not the problem. No matter what I do both libraries are still included in the final project

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an update.

I ended up linking the two library projects by including the 'common' in the build path and not as a library.

So, the question is - is this a bug or a feature? :)